# Firebase Push Notification with whitelabel android application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, white-labelling

I have an application which uses push notification from Firebase. However now i want to refactor my app and make it whitelabel so i have different application for each customer. Since the applicationId is different for each flavour how will i integrate Firebase now?
What package name do i have to declare to Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. The way to do this is to normally create one app in the Firebase project PER different applicationId for each flavor.
After that we can put the google-service.json file not necessarily in the app folder but in the top level of every flavor folder. After that everything goes like the normal..
Thnx

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would run up against the limit of 30 apps per FB project if you did this.  I have a similar issue and looks like I will have to create multiple FB projects.